# How to custom header message exception in DLQ

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to custom exception message in dead letter queue or add new header param with custom exception message.

Now I got raw stacktrace in header of dead letter queue message

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void consumer(Message<Content> message) {
    myService.update(message.getPayload().getData().getId());
}

messageInputChannel:
    consumer:
        enableDlq: true
        dlqName: error.message
        backOffInitialInterval: 15000 # the interval is 15s between each time retrying
        backOffMaxInterval: 30000 # the max interval is not over 30s between each time retrying
        maxAttempts: 3
        headerMode: raw
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear; with the RabbitMQ binder, you can set `republishToDlq` to get the exception in formation added to the message.

See [the documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.1.2.RELEASE/multi/multi__configuration_options.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties).

> **republishToDlq**
>
> By default, messages that fail after retries are exhausted are rejected. If a dead-letter queue (DLQ) is configured, RabbitMQ routes the failed message (unchanged) to the DLQ. If set to true, the binder republishs failed messages to the DLQ with additional headers, including the exception message and stack trace from the cause of the final failure. Also see the frameMaxHeadroom property.
>
> Default: false

With the Kafka binder, the exception information is always added to the dead letter record in headers; there is currently no mechanism to customize that information.

Comment: Now Im using Kafka when message publish to DLQ it will show x-exception-stacktrace node in header so I want to add another node with custom message exception. Thank for your reply.

Comment: You need to explain **exactly** what you want to do. `>"another node"` ? What does that mean? Some additional header? With the Kafka binder, the exception information is always added to the dead letter record in headers; there is currently no mechanism to customize that information. If you can explain what you want to do, it might be possible to add an extension point, or address the issue if you think something is missing.